# how does curl post data?

Tags: php, curl

so, I have this cURl code that I found a template for online

```
<?php

//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['ssl_merchant_id'] = 'xxx';
$post_data['ssl_user_id'] = 'xxx';
$post_data['ssl_pin'] = 'xxx';
$post_data['ssl_transaction_type'] = 'xxx';
$post_data['confirm_code'] = $_POST['confirm_code'];
$post_data['ssl_show_form'] = 'xxx';
$post_data['ssl_cardholder_ip'] = $_POST['ssl_cardholder_ip'];
$post_data['ssl_amount'] = $_POST['ssl_amount'];

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = 
  curl_init('xxx/cart2.php');

//set options

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
                curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
echo $result;
?>
```

My question is, how do I call the posted variables to be used on the cart2.php page
I will be filling in another form on cart2.php page with these posted variables then submitting that page to another page.  or is there some way I can place a redirect or something that will hold the post variables for the final page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
   //set POST variables
    $url = 'http://yourdomain.com/';
    $fields = array(
                        'ssl_merchant_id' => urlencode('xxxx'),
                            'field2' => urlencode(value2),
                            'field3' => urlencode(value3),
                            //field goes here 
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init('xxx/cart2.php');

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

And in your **cart2.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ssl_merchant_id'] )
$ssl_merchant_id=$_POST['ssl_merchant_id'];
?>
```

Comment: I added in an echo result and I get this:The document has moved here.
Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. 1

Comment: 302? The server returns  302, indicating a temporary redirection,have you changed $ch = curl_init('xxx/cart2.php'); to what it is?

Comment: ok, i have it working.  so is there no way to just place a redirect to hold the POST variables then?

Answer (score 0):

On `cart2.php`, you would use the $[_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) global:

```
var_dump($_POST['ssl_merchant_id']);
```

Note that you should check for its existence if you don't want to generate Notices and also want a default value:

```
function getPOST($key, $default = NULL) {
    return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : $default;
}

$ssl_merchant_id = getPOST('ssl_merchant_id');
if ($ssl_merchant_id) {
    // Do something
}
```

Or, you could use a less secure but more convenient method with [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

```
extract($_POST);
if (isset($ssl_merchant_id)) {
    // Do something
}
```